# Colorize space around points with the same color

Tags: matplotlib

I have a graphic with points of different colours depending on their class. It looks like the image below:
[image]

How can I plot this graphic without points, but with the same colour region around them to look like
[image]

Comment: look up `contourf`...

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Answer (score 0):

As @Quan mentioned, just use `contourf` matches my case